How do I get the actioncode value as 1(harddcoded) for the repeating lineitem and 3(hardcoded) for the not repeated line item in edifact invoice?
In a looping process of "n" line items (XML) within an occurrence group (EDIFACT), there's a scenario where a product "A" appears twice, once with a quantity of 100 and again with a quantity of 20 for later delivery. I'm translating this to an EDIFACT invoice. In the LIN segment, the client requests an action code value of 3 for all line items except for the second occurrence of the product with a quantity of 20, for which they require an action code value of 1. Currently, the hardcoded action code value is set to 3 for all line items. How can I implement this rule to set the action code to 1 only for that specific line item?
